# How to obtain the relation of eta invariant of the trivial gauge field and Chern-Simons invariant of the flat connection?

Tags: topological-field-theory, invariants, chern-simons-theory

In [Quantum Field Theory and the Jones Polynomial by Edward Witten(1989)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-121/issue-3/Quantum-field-theory-and-the-Jones-polynomial/cmp/1104178138.full),
how does $\eta(0)$ come from in this equation?
$$\frac{1}{2}(\eta(A^{(\alpha)})-\eta(0))=\frac{c_2}{2\pi}I(A^{(\alpha)})$$

$c_2(G)$ is the value of the quadratic Casimir operator of the group G in the adjoint representation. 
The flat connection $A^{(\alpha)}$ and its Chern-Simons invariant
$I(A^{(\alpha)}) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_M Tr (A^{(\alpha)}\wedge dA^{(\alpha)}+\frac{2}{3}A^{(\alpha)}\wedge A^{(\alpha)}\wedge A^{(\alpha)})$.

Comment: I may be wrong, but in general determinants of differential operators are defined as ratios. For example $\frac{\det(D)}{\det(\partial)}$. In the case of Witten's article, it seems to me that eq(2.15) implies a term $\sqrt{\det(\ast \partial + \partial \ast)}$ needed to counter infinities. The equation (2.16) is only here to say that since we *don't have* this counter term, eq(2.17) follows (specifically, the first exponential).

Comment: The infinite sum has been regularized by the zeta function in eta invariants. Does it cancel the counter terms you mention? But how it's related with adjoint representation and CS invariant?

Comment: I can't help you with this, because it is unfortunately beyond my knowledge (this is why I said "I may be wrong"). Witten mentions the Atiyah-Patodi-Singer theorem, and this is certainly the key point to understand (2.16)... I hope someone better than me will answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bath and some research, I think I figured it out. This is more of a long comment than an answer, though.

As you can see in this wonderful question on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315931/eta-invariant-and-atiyah-patodi-singer-index-theorem, it is not clear what Witten uses at first sight as, for short, the APS theorem amounts to the formula (in d+1 dimensions):
\begin{equation}
\text{ind} (\widehat{D}) = \frac{1}{8\pi^2}\int_M \text{tr}(F\wedge F)+\text{Curvature}-\frac{1}{2}(\eta(D_Y)+\dim \ker D_Y) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
There is a sign difference with the MO question because here we are in Lorentzian signature. The $\text{Curvature}$ part is purely expressed with the curvature of $M$. Here, $M$ is such that $\partial M = Y$, with $Y$ a 3d manifold in our case. But, according to the link in this MO question [Aspects of Boundary Problems in Analysis and Geometry](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0348-7850-0), page 145 on the document (page 158 if you take into account the beginning and the Contents), it is stated that if $D_Y$ is the signature operator (like a Dirac operator in our case), then we have that "An important corollary is the notable
generalization of Hirzebruch's signature formula to manifolds with boundary":
\begin{equation}
\text{sign}_A(M)=\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\int_M \text{tr}(F\wedge F)+\text{Curvature}-\frac{1}{2}\eta(D_Y) \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Of course, because $\partial M=Y$, and because $\text{tr}(F\wedge F)=d\text{CS}[A]$, we can subtract $\text{sign}_0(M)$ to $(2)$ to have:
\begin{equation}
\text{sign}_A(M)-\text{sign}_0(M)=\frac{C_2}{2\pi}I_\text{CS}[A]-\frac{1}{2}(\eta(D_Y)-\eta(d_Y)) \tag{3}
\end{equation}
Where $d_Y$ is the exterior derivative taking into account the spin connections. Now, I think that $\text{sign}_A(M)=\text{sign}_0(M)$ because in the book I linked, there is no mention of any dependence on a gauge field, so the formula should be true for the signature operators $d_Y$ too. Though I can't prove it, Witten's formula seems to imply this.

A word on the adjoint representation:

To me, it seems that $F\wedge F$ should be written as $\Omega \wedge \Omega$, where $\Omega$ is defined just like $F$ but for the gauge field $A$ in the adjoint representation. I think this simply comes from the fact that in (2.6) of Witten's article, $D$ acts on $B$, and a covariant derivative acting on a gauge field is expressed in the adjoint representation.